# Micronaut + GORM does not save domain deeply

Tags: groovy, grails-orm, micronaut

Trying update Execution domain, update only values from table execution

```
import grails.gorm.annotation.Entity

@Entity
class Execution {
    RatingItem price
    Boolean isDone
}
@Entity
class RatingItem {
    Boolean isDone
}
```

Saving in Transactional and Singleton Service called by a Controller

```
@Transactional
@Singleton
class ExecutionService{

    boolean saveExecution(Execution execution){
        if( execution.save(flush:true, failOnError:true) ){
            return true
        }
        return false
    }

}
```

Debugging..
execution.isDone is updated
execution.price.isDone not

After trasaction ends is_done in rating_item was not updated

This happens frequently. There is similar code that worked. In some cases I use DataSource to force update, but I need to use GORM this time.

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question but FYI I think that whole `saveExecution` method body could be simplified to just `execution.save(flush:true, failOnError:true)` and you could eliminate the `if(..) {}` and the `return` statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned before, there was similar code that worked. So I noticed that in this code I used the following:

```
Execution execution = Execution.findById(id)
```

And in the current problem:

```
Execution execution = Execution.get(id)
```

When I used findBy it worked.

I think it's because get doesn't fetch the domain correctly, even though all inner domains are lazy: false. I believe this does not happen in grails, but only in micronaut.